# Why were the Jews commanded to destroy fruit trees when attacking Moav?

Tags: army-military-war, nevua-prophecy, melachim-kings-book-of, trees

In 2 Melachim 3:24-25 it says

> They entered the Israelite camp, and the Israelites arose and attacked the Moabites, who fled before them. They advanced, constantly attacking the Moabites,
>   and they destroyed the towns. Every man threw a stone into each fertile field, so that it was covered over; and they stopped up every spring and **felled every fruit tree**. Only the walls of Kir-hareseth were left, and then the slingers surrounded it and attacked it.

However this violates Devarim 20:19

> When in your war against a city you have to besiege it a long time in order to capture it, you must not destroy its trees, wielding the ax against them. You may eat of them, but you must not cut them down. Are trees of the field human to withdraw before you into the besieged city?

Presumably the reason they did this is because the Navi told them to in pasuk 19

> You shall conquer every fortified town and every splendid city; **you shall fell every good tree** and stop up all wells of water; and every fertile field you shall ruin with stones.

I would like to understand why this was commanded. Presumably they could have won the battle without destroying the trees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rashi and Radak give similar answers which amount to - this nation was not included in that prohibition because they are so awful.

[רש"י, מלכים ב' ג:י"ט](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.3.19?lang=he&with=Rashi&lang2=he):‏

> **וכל עץ טוב תפילו**. אף על פי שנאמר (דברים כ יט): לא תשחית את עצה, כאן התיר לכם, שהיא אומה בזויה ונקלית לפניו, וכן הוא אומר (שם כג ז): לא תדרוש שלומם וטובתם, אלו האילנות הטובים שבהם:‏

[רד"ק, מלכים ב' ג:י"ט](https://www.sefaria.org.il/II_Kings.3.19?lang=he&with=Radak&lang2=he):‏

> **וכל עץ טוב תפילו**. כי הכתוב לא אמר לא תשחית את עצה אלא כשיצורו על עיר כמ"ש הטעם כי ממנו תאכל ואע"פ שרז"ל קבלו כי בכל מקום ובכל זמן אסור להשחית עץ מאכל פשט הכתוב הוא שלא אמר אלא בעת המצור ואפשר שהיתה מצוה לשעה כאליהו בהר הכרמל שהקריב עולה בחוץ בשעת איסור הבמות, ובדרש כשאמר להם הנביא וכל עץ טוב תפילו אמרו לו הרי הוא אומר לא תשחית את עצה ואתה אומר כן אמר להם על שאר האומות נאמרה זה אבל אומה זו נקלה ונבזה לפני ה' שנאמר ונקל זאת בעיני ה' ונאמר לא תדרוש שלומם וטובתם אלו אילנות טובות שלהם:‏

Mahari Kara says this is retribution for Moav not offering food and drink - this didn't behave properly with you, you should also not behave properly with them (by destroying the fruit trees).